# What does this Javascript syntax mean?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am working with ROS structure and facing some problem with debugging, and I found this snippet:

```
ros.visualization.GLNode = Class.extend({
    init: function () {
        this.meshGroupIDs = [ ];
        this.matrix       = sglIdentityM4();
        this.children     = [ ];
    },
});
```

What do these lines mean?

**ros.visualization.GLnode** :: Is it trying to load some files? What does this `.` represent?

**Class.extend**::  What does this do? Is it trying to extend the class, and if so then which one? In my way it will be `GLnode`.

**this.matrix:: I always have doubts when I see `this` command what does it do?**

init : function() :: What does this function mean in js? Is it a keyword? If not then why does everyone use it in `onloadbody` or `window.onload()`?

Comment: I think one of the best way to answer all of your questions would be to go through a primer on javascript to learn of the language features and usage.. this is one I love: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/a_re-introduction_to_javascript

Comment: I found something useful which may help you too http://code.google.com/p/oopsjs/ http://tinyway.wordpress.com/2010/09/05/inside-object-oriented-javascript-explained-part-1/ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ros.visualization.GLNode = Class.extend({
```

This is the definition of a new class (or type of object) using some sort of javascript library that has the function Class.extend() in it.

---

```
init: function () {
```

This is the definition of an attribute on the new class called "init".  The type of the attribute is "function" which means it works like a method and can be called.

---

```
this.meshGroupIDs = [ ];
```

This is the definition of a member variable on an object of this class and initializes it to an empty array.

---

```
this.matrix = sglIdentityM4();
```

This is the definition of another member variable on an object of thisclass and initializes it to the return value from the sglIdentityM4() function call.

---

```
this.children = [ ];
```

This is the definition of a member variable on an object of this class and initializes it to an empty array.

---

"this" is a reference to the local object and is how you address instance variables of the object you are in.

Answer (score 1):

#### ros.visualization.GLNode

The `.` operator lets you access object properties, so `ros.visualization.GLNode = ...` means that there is an object called `ros`, with a `visualization` property, and you are assigning something to the `GLNode` property of that object.

#### Class.extend

`Class.extend` isn't a built-in part of JavaScript, so without knowing how it was defined, it's impossible to know exactly what it's doing. I can guess from the name and how it's used that it creates a new "class" or extends an existing one. The code is passing an object literal (the `{ ... }` part) that tells it how to define the class.

#### this.matrix

`this` is the context that a function was called in. When you call a function on an object (in this case, `someGLNodeObject.init()`), `this` gets set to that object. So `this.matrix = sglIdentityM4();` is setting the `matrix` property of the current object.

#### init: function()

Defines a function in the object literal called `init`. The `Class.extend` function presumably uses the `init` function like a constructor to initialize new `GLnode` instances.